# Django: cascade on_delete option not working

Tags: database, django, foreign-keys, cascade

I am using django 1.2.4 (Confirmed through the shell with `import django` `django.VERSION`) and am attempting to use the `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` setting on a `ForeignKeyField` but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SET_NULL'
```

This is how I was attempting to use the setting:

```
relatedRec = models.ForeignKey(Record, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

The model was already created and I am now trying to alter it. I didnt think that would be a problem but maybe it is...

Am I doing this properly or are there any tircks/issues with what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`on_delete`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) argument is new in Django 1.3 which will be released in a couple of weeks (or days, it was projected for [January 31](http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/jan/05/django-1_3-release-schedule-update/), but that date could slip, since there is no release candidate yet).

Current trunk or the Beta 1 of Django 1.3 are perfectly fine for development, but I wouldn't risk using it in production just yet.

Comment: The docs at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ are for current trunk (i.e. not yet released). The docs for Django 1.2 are at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/

Comment: ah ok thanks. Its pretty convenient that the release date is so soon!