# on_delete=models.SET_NULL option in ForeignKey field has no effect

Tags: mysql, django

I have two Django models having a foreign key referring to the other one:

```
class Style(models.Model):
    featured_item = models.ForeignKey('Item', blank=True, null=True)
    # more fields

class Item(models.Model):
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style, blank=True, null=True) 
    # more fields
```

when deleting instances of `Item` I get a an IntegrityError:

```
In [4]: cursor.execute("DELETE FROM myapp_item WHERE n = 0)

IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`myapp_style`, CONSTRAINT `featured_item_id_refs_id_578e3e581685bdae` FOREIGN KEY (`featured_item_id`) REFERENCES `myapp_item` (`id`))')
```

so I added the `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` option to the `featured_item` foreign key field of my `Style` model, i.e. replaced

```
featured_item = models.ForeignKey('Item', blank=True, null=True)
```

by

```
featured_item = models.ForeignKey('Item', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

and migrate my database (which already had data) using South.

But I still get the foreign key constraint error when deleting an `Item` instance.

I'm using Django 1.5.

Anybody can help?

Comment: you have foreignkey referring to one another, is this a good practice?

Comment: @catherine: I know it's not a good practice. I should use another table for this 'featured_item' field, but if this on_delete stuff works, I'll save a lot of time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823182/django-cascade-on-delete-option-not-working

Comment: @catherine: this link seems of no help

Comment: yeah, I just want you to read the risk of what you are doing.

Comment: @catherine: I'm using Django 1.5, so this should be ok.

Comment: @jul Does it work in Django 1.5? I am able to run the migration successfully, however it still deletes the foreign key object instead of marking the field as null.